# Проверка на null в java

Tags: java, android, null

Проверка на null в java,

```
 if(object==null){ 
    return;
    }
```

весь проект состоит из проверки на null, есть какая нибудь альтернатива? чтобы код был красивый

Comment: Приведите больше кода, из этого кусочка сложно предложить что-то получше.

Comment: Пишите на kotlin'e

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В Java 8 был добавлен класс Optional, чтобы добавить новый подход к обработке null. Optional является некоторой оболочкой над значением (функтором), в которой может либо быть конкретное значение, либо нет. Например, можно сделать так:

```
Integer reputation = Optional.ofNullable(users.get(userId)).map(User::getReputation).orElseGet(null);
```

В этом случае если users.get вернул null, код в map выполнен не будет. Это позволяет довольно легко писать длинные куски кода без необходимости задумываться о null:

```
// дурацкий пример, ничего лучше не придумал
Node fifthLevelChild = Optional.of(root)
        // представим, что .get(0) может вернуть либо элемент, либо null, 
        // и не стреляет исключением
        .map(node -> node.getChildren().get(0))
        .map(node -> node.getChildren().get(0))
        .map(node -> node.getChildren().get(0))
        .map(node -> node.getChildren().get(0))
        .map(node -> node.getChildren().get(0))
        .orElseGet(null);
```

Если же проверка на null у вас происходит для преждевременного окончания куска кода (e.g. передан null -> остановить работу), то здесь лучше обозначить публичный интерфейс того компонента, который вы пишете (я не про интерфейс как окнструкцию языка), и выполнять проверку ключевых моментов на null в нем, чтобы ваш внутренний код просто не мог получить null.